# website hosted in aws ec2 is not loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, traceroute

I have a website hosted in aws ec2 which stopped loading since few days onwards no clue whatsoever, below the output of traceroute please help

```
Tracing route to 126news.com [18.221.68.117]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     3 ms     1 ms  WirelessAP [192.168.1.1]
  2     6 ms    20 ms     3 ms  10.111.192.1
  3     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  10.229.0.13
  4     3 ms     3 ms     4 ms  broadband.actcorp.in [183.82.14.221]
  5     3 ms     3 ms     6 ms  14.141.24.169.static-hyderabad.tcl.net.in [14.141.24.169]
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7    33 ms    28 ms    29 ms  ix-ae-4-2.tcore1.cxr-chennai.as6453.net [180.87.36.9]
  8    65 ms    64 ms    68 ms  if-ae-13-2.tcore1.svw-singapore.as6453.net [180.87.36.83]
  9   100 ms    67 ms    70 ms  if-ae-11-2.thar1.svq-singapore.as6453.net [180.87.98.37]
 10    64 ms    66 ms    64 ms  ae-6.r00.sngpsi05.sg.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.8.241]
 11    64 ms    72 ms    64 ms  ae-10.r20.sngpsi05.sg.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.7.18]
 12   247 ms   240 ms   240 ms  ae-8.r22.snjsca04.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.48]
 13   243 ms   245 ms   249 ms  ae-8.r21.chcgil09.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.5.16]
 14   244 ms   244 ms   245 ms  ae-2.r07.chcgil09.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.4.214]
 15   249 ms   248 ms   249 ms  ae-1.a01.chcgil09.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.5.94]
 16   246 ms   252 ms   361 ms  ae-2.amazon.chcgil09.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.201.106]
 17   262 ms   284 ms   255 ms  52.95.62.122
 18   261 ms   261 ms   262 ms  52.95.62.125
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20   260 ms   263 ms   259 ms  54.239.46.161
 21   256 ms   272 ms   258 ms  54.239.43.225
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24   260 ms   258 ms   261 ms  52.95.1.234
 25   255 ms   258 ms   255 ms  52.95.1.247
 26   262 ms   259 ms   256 ms  52.95.1.106
 27   259 ms   259 ms   260 ms  52.95.1.87
 28   253 ms   253 ms   252 ms  52.95.3.142
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Trace complete.

Comment: HTTPERR log shows Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue

Comment: issue is resolved after I deleted .cshtml files from a folder that has many files